# replacing telnet with ssh

Tags: perl, ssh, telnet

I have some programs that use the Net::Telnet module to connect to several servers. Now the administrators have decided to replace the Telnet service for SSH, keeping everything else like before (for example the user accounts)

I've taken a look at Net::SSH2 and I see that I would have to change most part of the programs. Do you know of other SSH modules, better suited for this same replacement?

The client is a Windows box (ActiveState Perl or Cygwin Perl)

Comment: [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com)

Comment: Do you mean that Net::OpenSSH works with Strawberry Perl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your suggestions, but I finally used Net::SSH::Perl on ActivePerl for Windows

Pros:

- quite similar to Net::Telnet. There is no close method, but instead of `$host->close` you can do `$host->cmd("exit")`
- native Perl implementation

Cons:

- each `cmd()` call has a different state, for example it doesn't keep the current directory between calls, like Net::Telnet did
- needs a modification in the module code to work on Windows, see: https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=18154
- `cmd("su - user")` doesn't work, but `cmd("su - user -c 'commands'")` does

Answer (score 3):

[Net::OpenSSH](http://p3rl.org/Net%3a%3aOpenSSH)!

And check the chapter about [how to integrate it with Net::Telnet](http://p3rl.org/Net%3a%3aOpenSSH#Net%3a%3aTelnet).

Comment: :/ forgot to say it was for Windows