# Perl Net::Telnet retrieving single line of output

Tags: perl, telnet

Using Perl's Net::Telnet module to retrieve data from upsd.
There is one particular function I'm trying to implement, retrieving the data for a single var.
The problem is only a single line is output, and that line is used to match
Prompt, so it is not output.

Here's raw telnet:

```
telnet dns1 3493
Trying 192.168.15.1...
Connected to dns1.
Escape character is '^]'.
get var cp1500 ups.test.result
VAR cp1500 ups.test.result "Done and passed"
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Here's some code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::Telnet;

my $host = "dns1";
my $model = "cp1500";
my $bvar = "ups.test.result";
my $t = new Net::Telnet (Timeout => 3, Port => 3493, Prompt => "/VAR $model $bvar/");
$t->open($host);
my @ary = $t->cmd("get var $model $bvar");
print @ary,"\n";
```

This just prints the newline as the array is empty. Prompt is matched else there'd be a timeout error. How can I get that single line of output back for processing in the script?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8805369/725418

Comment: @TLP Can you explain how that post helps, thanks

Comment: It was more a general suggestion to replace Telnet with SSH. Telnet feels very antiquated. But maybe [Net::SSH::Expect](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Net-SSH-Expect/lib/Net/SSH/Expect.pod) is more suitable.

Comment: Perhaps you need to specify a `Prompt` -- _This method sends the command $string, and reads the characters sent back by the command up until and including the matching prompt. It's assumed that the program to which you're sending is some kind of command prompting interpreter such as a shell._ [doc](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Telnet). And perhaps you intended `print $_ . "\n" for @ary;`.

Comment: `cmd()` returns *all the characters in between the echoed back command string and the prompt*. So it stops reading once it has matched `"VAR cp1500 ups.test.result"`. You might be able to then get the rest of the line with `getline()`. The lack of a real command prompt from the system is real problem. You might be better off just using print and waitfor or getline/getlines.

Comment: @meuh Only one line is returned, and its got to be used for Prompt matching.

In any case I elected to go with Socket module as this is better suited for my needs.

Comment: @TLP upsd provides a simple tcp interface. Telnet or netcat can talk to it so i figured Net::Telnet would work, and it does except for the situation where you expect one line of output, but that same line must be used to match Prompt, thus making the line unavailble to use in the script. I'm using the Socket module instead, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution, use Socket instead of Net::Telnet.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Socket;

my $host = 'str003';
my $port = 3493;
my $model = 'cp1350';
my $quer = 'get var';
my $bvar = 'ups.test.result';
my ($sock,$iaddr,$paddr,$send);
$iaddr = inet_aton($host);
$paddr = sockaddr_in($port, $iaddr);
$send = join(' ',$quer,$model,$bvar);
socket($sock, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 6) or die $!;
connect($sock , $paddr) or die "connect failed : $!";
send($sock , "$send\nlogout\n" , 0);
while (my $line = <$sock>)
{
  if ($line =~ /^VAR/) {
    print "$line\n";
  }
}
close($sock);
```

This is the one where one line of data is returned:

```
VAR cp1350 ups.test.result "Done and passed"
```